# Aero Peek on multiple monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, aero-peek

I have two 27" monitors, my main one is the one on the left and this has the notification area, time/date and the the Aero Peek button on the bottom most right. I want the second monitor to also display those things or at minimum, just the peek button.

If I make the monitor on my right the main monitor I can get those things there but ideally I want them on both.

Is there a way to do this natively? I know "Actual Multiple Monitors" and "Display Fusion" can do this but I'd like know to if this can be done natively before trying the above.

[EDIT]

I have tried both Display Fusion and Actual Multiple Monitors, both are not good enough. Display Fusion forces me to use its own inferior taskbar and startmenu and Actual Multiple monitors doesn't allow me to use the start8 start menu instead or completely disable the start menu for that taskbar.

[EDIT 2]

Workaround, installed latest Actual Multiple Monitors and disabled secondary start menu as its not compatible with start8. Having two different looking start menus isn't really ideal so i'll just have to do without one until they get this sorted.

Comment: the notification area and aero peek are independent of each other. While I'd like both, id settle just for aero peek on both monitors. That question has nothing to with aero peek?

Comment: Congratulations but no they're not the same. The notification is independent, just because they're next to each other doesn't mean they're dependent..

Comment: This has nothing to do with I personally feel, this is not a dupe like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The new Taskbar in **Windows 8** finally spans multiple monitors, and can be customized so that the taskbar buttons on each monitor are the buttons for windows open on that monitor. You can also make both taskbars show all windows if you choose.

To access the new settings, head into Taskbar Properties by right-clicking on the Taskbar and choosing Properties. Once there, you’ll see the “Multiple displays” section at the bottom of the dialog, where you can quickly check the box to enable or disable showing the taskbar across displays.[howtogeek.com]

[image: Taskbar Properties Windows 8]

Comment: I already have the taskbar on both monitors, the second monitor doesn't show the notification area, time/date and the show desktop button.

Comment: Ok i see now. Well i think that is not possible to do just with Windows 8, you will need additional software.